# SQL Statement combining LTRIM(REPLACE(substr & INSTR

Tags: sql, replace, substr

I'm obviously new to SQL and trying to understand what these two statements below are doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Statement 1

```
LTRIM(REPLACE(substr(full_name, INSTR (full_name,','), length(full_name)),','))
```

Statement 2

```
REPLACE(RPAD(FULL_NAME, INSTR (full_name,',')),',','') "Name"
```

Comment: Both statements are related to splitting out first and last name from a full name, but you need post more of your code for a full explanation.